# How to use the date command

Tags: linux

How to use the `date` command to display, for example, `10-Mar-2010 01:01:53`? What's the format string?

Comment: Is your `man` page broken?  Is Google down?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [date manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date):

```
date '+%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

Answer (score 3):

Read the manpage (`man date`)!

```
date +"%d-%b-%Y %T"
```